# what is open wire protocol in ActiveMQ

Tags: protocols, activemq-classic

I noticed that in active mq connection example with  tag we use name = "openwire". When I looked into that , it is a wire level protocol. Actually what is it for?
Also noticed there are several such protocols it supprot. Then which one i choose?

Answer (score 1):

Openwire is ActiveMQ's default wire level protocol.  The Java, C++ and .NET clients all use this protocol.  If you are using the provided ActiveMQ libraries then you don't need to worry about it.  For other scripting type languages we also support the STOMP protocol and in the latest release we support both AMQP and MQTT connections.

Comment: Ok..can u explain the use of this 'wire level protocol'

Comment: You probably want to read some text books if you don't know what the wire level protocol does.